# Blur image performance issues on iOS simulator 10.2.1

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

I use this code to blur my `UIImage`

```
extension UIImage {
    func blurred(radius: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return self }
        let inputImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        guard let ciFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur") else { return self }
        ciFilter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        ciFilter.setValue(radius, forKey: "inputRadius")
        guard let resultImage = ciFilter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage else { return self }
        guard let cgImage2 = ciContext.createCGImage(resultImage, from: inputImage.extent) else { return self }
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage2)
    }
}
```

But it takes so long to return image from this operation.

Actually this operation takes about 2 seconds:
`guard let cgImage2 = ciContext.createCGImage(resultImage, from: inputImage.extent) else { return self` }

I have not tested it on real device, but not sure if the code is efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code looks fine-ish, though you should cache the image it returns rather than calling it repeatedly if at all possible; as Matt points out in the comments below, you should also use a shared CIContext rather than setting a new one up every time.

The performance issue you’re seeing is due to the simulator having very different performance characteristics from real hardware. It sounds like Core Image is either using the simulator’s emulated OpenGL ES interface (which is slow) or the CPU (which is slower). Testing it on an iOS device will give you a much better idea of the performance you should expect.

Comment: You should cache the context. Creating a new CIContext is expensive.

Comment: I upvoted @matt comment - this answer is partially helpful, as simulator performance of CI is pathetic. But you probably should add how wrong it is to ignore what creating multiple `CIContexts` mean. to be honest, I'm expecting (hoping?) that WWDC19 brings some much needed changes to how CoreImage operates in the simulator... what with GLKit deprecation and Marzipan among other requirements, the least they can do is make Metal "native" to it.

Comment: Good news: With iOS 13 + Xcode 11 + macOS 10.15 CoreImage uses Metal in Simulator and is hardware-accelerated by the GPU. 
Also I would not hold onto the `CIContext()` forever, otherwise you can end up consuming a lot of texture memory and getting terminated.